# How to pass multiple parameters to @RequestBody using JavaScript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, spring

I have that POST method:

```
function saveSchemaInDatabase(schemaName) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", "/user/saveSchemaInDatabase", true);
    xhttp.send(schemaName);
}
```

and i am catching that shoot in my controller in that way:

```
@PostMapping(path = { "/user/saveSchemaInDatabase" })
public String saveSchemaInDatabase(@RequestBody String schemaName) {

    return "redirect:/user";
}
```

Can someone tell me how i can send multiple params to that controller? For example i want something like that:

```
//shoot
function saveSchemaInDatabase(schemaName, diagramJson) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", "/user/saveSchemaInDatabase", true);
    xhttp.send(schemaName, diagramJson);
}

//catch
@PostMapping(path = { "/user/saveSchemaInDatabase" })
public String saveSchemaInDatabase(@RequestBody String schemaName, @RequestBody String diagramJson) {

    return "redirect:/user";
}
```

I hope you know what i mean. Of course my way doesn't work. Error 400 appears.

[image]

Can someone help me? Im done :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crete FormData object and add as many values as you want inside it

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("email", "eve.holt@reqres.in");
data.append("password", "pistol");
```

Then send this formData object to the post request

Like this

```
xhttp.send(data);
```

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me what kind of variable type i should put now into my controller to handle that "data" ?

Comment: You should parse the data as json object on your controller and then get values from keys that we appended inside data